# Footnote in moderncv

Tags: footnotes, moderncv

I'm using the `moderncv` template and I want to add a footnote inside the last part of the `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}` tag, something like this:

```
\cventry{Aug 2008}{Title}{}{}{}{text text text \footnote{footnote text} text text text.}
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX inserts the footnote directly under the `\cventry` instead of at the bottom of the page. I already included `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` in the preamble but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Answer (score 20):

moderncv places many of its items in LaTeX `minipages` which have their own footnote areas.

You may use `\footnotemark` at the point that you want the mark and `\footnotetext{some text}` at a point in the source document that is at the outer level and can allow the footnote to migrate to the bottom of the main page.

Comment: In my texlive 2015 this doesn't work out of the box. moderncv doesn't seem to define `\@makefntext` breaking `\footnotetext`. And using `\footnotemark` in the institution field of a `\cventry` causes a runaway argument error, perhaps due to the internal workings of `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: Note for others reading: this suggestion does require `\usepackage{footmisc}` in your header

Comment: @Jeremy ??? both the commands I mention are defined in the format and require no package at all.

Comment: I would like to add that in my case also the usual `\footnote{text}` command works after including the `\usepackage{footmisc}` package.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @David Carlisle's answer, I'd add that if you place your `footnotetext` at the "end" of a page, it might not end up all the way down the page, depending on whether the page is filled or not.

Also, you might want the footnote to appear in the footer of the CV if you use a template that doesn't use the footer.

In order to achieve these, you can use:

```
\vfill
\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\footnotetext{Your footnote text}
```